# clCreateImage2D (..., void* hst_ptr,..) how to use it?

Tags: c++, opencl

I read the formal definition on the official site but still I dont understand: What is void* hst-ptr used for? For example [here](http://opencl-book-samples.googlecode.com/svn-history/r22/trunk/src/Chapter_8/ImageFilter2D/ImageFilter2D.cpp). Why is buffer here so useful, Why buffer is a pointer to char and the size is 4*width*height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`host_ptr` is used when either of the flags `CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR` or `CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR` are specified. In those cases, `host_ptr` points to CPU memory containing an image to use or copy.

In the example code you linked to, `buffer` is the host-side (CPU memory) image being copied to the device-side (GPU typ.) image (since they are using the `CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR` flag).

It's not important that they made it a pointer to char since they are using `memcpy` to fill it in, but it helps the allocation using `new char` since a char is 1 byte in size.

`4 * width * height` is because that is the total number of bytes (chars) needed.

1. `4` is the size of one CL_RGBA CL_UNORM_INT8 pixel (R, G, B, A are each one byte).
2. `width * height` because that the total count of pixels.

The code is allocating host-side memory for an image, filling it in with something, then creating a device-side image using those bytes, then processing it using a kernel, then copying the bytes back to the host-side image.

Comment: Would be the same to use clEnqueueWriteImage?

Comment: Sure, you could just allocate the image (without `CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR` or `CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR`) and then write to it using `clEnqueueWriteImage`).